# : Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Tags: spring

I am  facing the below error while executing the below code.

I have my class names as below.

class Dad.java

```html
package TestingDependecy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Dad {

 private Mom mom;
 private Child child;
 
 public Dad (Mom mom) {
  this.mom = mom;
 }
 
 public Dad (Child child) {
  this.child = child;
 }
 
 public void name() throws IOException {
  System.out.println("please enter a  name ..");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String name = br.readLine();
  System.out.println("Please confirm your deatails below");
  System.out.println("Your name is  "+ name);
 }
 public void whichWork() {
  mom.cooking();
 }
 
 public void mainWork() {
 
  System.out.println("Don't distrub me Please...!!");
  child.main();
 }
 
 
}
```

class Mom.java

```html
package TestingDependecy;

public class Mom {

 public void cooking() {
  System.out.println("I am cooking ");
  System.out.println(" what else i can do ?");
  
 }
}
```

Class Child

```html
package TestingDependecy;

public class Child {

 
 public void main() {
  System.out.println("This is from child class");
 }
}
```

Class Family.java

```html
package TestingDependecy;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import TestingDependecy.Dad;

public class Family {

 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
  
  Dad d = context.getBean("dad", Dad.class);
  d.mainWork();
  System.out.println();
  d.whichWork();
  context.close();
  
 }
}
```

Finally my ApplicationContext.xml file as below

ApplicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


<!-- This is for family Package -->
<bean id = "mom" 
 class="TestingDependecy.Mom"> 
 </bean>
 
<bean id = "child" 
 class="TestingDependecy.Child"> 
 </bean> 
<bean id = "dad" 
 class="TestingDependecy.Dad">
 
 <constructor-arg ref="mom"/>
 <constructor-arg ref="child"/>
 </bean>
```

I'm getting the below while executing the code.

Please find the error below.

```html
May 04, 2018 8:45:02 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a1cd57: startup date [Fri May 04 08:45:01 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
May 04, 2018 8:45:02 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]
May 04, 2018 8:45:02 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dad' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dad' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:243)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
 at TestingDependecy.Family.main(Family.java:13)
```

Please help me on this, what is the mistake I did here?

Regards,
Saikiran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `ApplicationContext.xml` you've passed two arguments to the constructor of `dad` bean :

```
<bean id = "dad" 
  class="TestingDependecy.Dad">

   <constructor-arg ref="mom"/>
   <constructor-arg ref="child"/>
</bean>
```

So you have to define a two-argument constructor in `Dad` class like this:

```
public class Dad {

   private Mom mom;
   private Child child;

   public Dad (Mom mom, Child child) {
       this.mom = mom;
       this.child = child;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Dariush Jafari,

i am facing different error.
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Could not convert argument value of type [TestingDependecy.Child] to required type [TestingDependecy.Mom]: Failed to convert value of type 'TestingDependecy.Child' to required type 'TestingDependecy.Mom'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'TestingDependecy.Child' to required type 'TestingDependecy.Mom': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: The order of arguments is important!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Dariush.. :)

it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE
all keep one constructor and corresponding bean constructor class

```
<bean id="e" class="com.test.Employee">
<constructor-arg value="12" type="int"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="UP"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg> <ref bean="a1"/> </constructor-arg >
<constructor-arg> <ref bean="company"/> </constructor-arg>
</bean>

public Employee(int idx, String name, Address address, Company company) {
    this.idx=idx;
    this.name=name;
    this.address=address;
    this.company=company;   
}
```